# How to make a percentage from baseball player stats

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get a program to converts stats of a baseball player to a whole percentage. Not a decimal.

I have googled and youtubed. No one has the answer I need.

```
##Batter: Charlie Blackmon
##At Bats: 514
##Hits: 164
##Total Bases: 299
##Home Runs: 27
##Strike Outs: 93
##
##Batting Stats:
##Batting Average: 0
##Slugging Average: 0
##Home Run Percentage: 0
##Strike Out Percentage: 0


#initializations:
atBats = 514
hits = 164
totalBases = 299
homeRuns = 27
strikeOut = 93

print ("atBats",atBats)
print ("hits",hits)
print ("totalBases",totalBases)
print ("homeRuns",homeRuns)
print ("strikeOut",strikeOut)

##Chunk 1: Inputs
atBats = int(input("Enter the At Bats:"))
hits = int(input("Enter the Hits:"))
totalBases = int(input("Enter Total Bases:"))
homeRuns = float(input("Enter Home Runs:"))
strikeOut = float(input("Enter Strike Out:"))

print ("atBats",atBats)
print ("hits",hits)
print ("totalBases",totalBases)
print ("homeRuns",homeRuns)
print ("strikeOut",strikeOut)

##Chunk 2 Process
battingAverage = atBats / hits / totalBases #float
sluggingAverage = atBats / hits / totalBases #float
homeRunsPercentage = homeRuns * strikeOut / 100 #int
strikeOutPercentage = homeRuns / strikeOut * 100 #int

##Chunk 3 Output
print ("At Bats",atBats)
print ("Hits",hits)
print ("Total Bases",totalBases)
print ("Home Runs",homeRuns)
print ("Strike Out",strikeOut)
print ("Batting Average",battingAverage)
print ("Slugging Average",sluggingAverage)
print ("Home Runs Percentage",homeRunsPercentage)
print ("Strike Out Percentage",strikeOutPercentage)
```

I need to get the Home Runs Percentage to be able to show the percentage sign after the program is executed. It is for school. eg 25.11 needs to be 25%.

Comment: I am being taught to do it the way it is set now. Plus all my numbers that I am adding together are whole numbers. So not sure how I could just put a decimal in there.

Comment: I am also supposed to be putting this in a table format. Yet when I click tabify region I get the sound of a window pop-up but no pop-up. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes:

Line 32+33:

```
homeRuns = int(input("Enter Home Runs:"))
strikeOut = int(input("Enter Strike Out:"))
```

Not sure why you casted the input to float there, seems like int is the correct choice.

Line 55+56:

```
print ("Home Runs Percentage", str(round(homeRunsPercentage))+"%")
print ("Strike Out Percentage", str(round(strikeOutPercentage))+"%")
```

If you want to round a number to the closest integer, you have to, well, `round` it. Further, if you just print them separated by a `,`, python adds a space in between, so to print the `%` directly after the number, you have to cast the number to a `str` and then concatenate it with the `"%"`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Round would maybe not be the best choice.
Look:

```py
>>> round(20.5)
20
```

This is only correct for Computers :-D

You should better round this way:

```py
>>> int(20.5 + 0.5)
21
```

Rounding this way you wont get the floating point rounding errors.

If you want to round to a specific part after comma do:

```py
>>> int(20.5555555555 * 1000 + 0.5) / 1000
20.556
```

Comment: Those are not floating point rounding errors. This is intentional and called [bankers' rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). It removes the bias from the rounding result by sometimes rounding up, sometimes down. There is no reason why 20.5 _should_ be rounded to 21, except of the formal definition that you learn at school. 20.5 is exactly as far away from 21 as from 20.